# Number of consecutive values above certain cut off

Tags: bash, awk

I am new in bash and linux programming. I have a small problem.

For a particular cut-off (c) I want to dump a file which will print out values above c if two consecutive values are above c. For example

```
x y
1 0.34
2 0.3432
3 0.32
4 0.35
5 0.323
6 0.3623
7 0.345
```

It will print out column 2 if c=0.33

```
0.34
0.3432
0.3623
0.345
```

It will not print out 0.35 despite it was above cut off 0.33 because the next value after 0.35 was 0.323 which fails the argument 'two consecutive values are above c'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Question:** *print all sequences where 2 or more consecutive values satisfy a given condition*

The following should work :

```
awk 'p || (prev>c && $2>c && NR>2){print prev}
     { p = (prev>c && $2>c); prev=$2 }
     END{if(p) print $2 }' c=0.33 <file>
```

It makes the following logic :

- `p` keeps track if the previous line has been printed. If it is printed then the current line should also be printed.
- If the previous line is not printed (`p==0`), then you should check if you should print the previous line if `(prev>c && $2>c)`
- Compute `p` for the next line and set `prev` to the current value
- At the end, if `p==1` print the last value.

You essentially always run one line behind.

Another way to approach this is checking if the value satisfies the condition and store it in an array. If you encounter a value that does not satisfy the condition, process the array. This is a bit more memory intensive :

```
awk '(NR==1){next}
     ($2>c) { a[NR]=$2; next }
     (length(a) == 1) { delete a[NR-1]; next }
     { for(i=NR-length(a);i<NR;++i) {print a[i]; delete a[i]} }
     END { if (length(a)>1) for(i=NR+1-length(a);i<=NR;++i) {print a[i]} }
    ' c=0.33 <file>
```

**Second question:** *print the subset of consecutive values of $2 for which `m` or more values satisfy condition `cond` and at most `n` consecutive values do not satisfy `cond`. The sequence starts and ends with a value satisfying `cond`*

The following `awk` script will do this. Don't forget to adjust the values `m`, `n` and `c` to your wishes and update the conditional function.

```
function cond(val) { return val > c }
BEGIN{c=0.33; m=2; n=1}
# skip the header
(NR==1){next}
# if no values satisfy cond ...
(M==0 && !cond($2)) { next }
# ... otherwise continue from here
{ a[NR]=$2 }
# set counters M and N (M satisfy cond, N not )
 cond($2) { M++; N=0 }
!cond($2) { N++ }
# This sequence failed, delete it
(N>n && M<m) { for(i in a) delete a[i]; M=0; N=0 }
# This sequence is OK, strip it and print it
(N>n) { j=NR; while (!cond(a[j])) delete a[j--]
        for (i=j+1-length(a);i<=j;++i) { print a[i]; delete a[i] }
        M=0; N=0 }
# Check if the final stored sequence is successful
END { if (M>=m) { 
         j=NR; while (!cond(a[j])) delete a[j--]
         for (i=j+1-length(a);i<=j;++i) print a[i]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Well it printed out 0.34
0.3623
0.345 not 0.34
0.3432
0.3623
0.345 maybe something wrong here?

Comment: Awsome. Maybe I was not clear in the question but the criteria is m='minimum two consecutive values are above c'. That doesn't mean if there is 3 or multiple consecutive values above c it will exclude. I think this script is taking into account that as per my test. Thanks

Comment: However it doesn't work if I edit the script like this  awk 'p || (prev<c && $2<c && NR>2){print prev}
     { p = (prev<c && $2<c); prev=$2 }
     END{if(p) print $2 }' c=0.33 test.dat that means same philosophy but less than the cutoff

Comment: Also another problem: for values in the question 0.32
0.35
0.323 if the c is 0.33 and I want values lower than c it will print out 0.32 and 0.323 but I also want to print out 0.35 because that is just one occurrence of above the c which doesn't follow my rule as mentioned in m hence it will also be printed out. Any way to do it?

Comment: sorry I should have phrased my question more correctly. Now the question is edited accordingly as per my second question.

Comment: ./closed.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `val'
./closed.sh: line 2: `function cond(val) { return val > c }'
I am using like ./closed.sh test.dat

Comment: @RoyBanerjee this is an `awk` script and not a Shell script, you should run it accordingly `awk -f awk_file test.dat` or you place the entire thing between quotes and call it `awk ' <full code>' test.dat`

Comment: @RoyBanerjee I think by now this should have answered all your questions. Please don't forget to have a look at [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Something wrong here for test.dat 1 0.34
2 0.3432
3 0.32
4 0.35
5 0.323
6 0.31
7 0.29
8 0.3623
9 0.345 It should print out  0.32 0.35 0.323 0.31 0.29 but it is printing 0.3432
0.32
0.35
0.3623
0.345
 this cant be true right?

Comment: @RoyBanerjee you forgot to add the header

Comment: It has a header x y
1 0.34
2 0.3432
3 0.32
4 0.35
5 0.323
6 0.31
7 0.29
8 0.3623
9 0.345 but the output is still 0.34
0.3432
0.32
0.35
0.3623
0.345 Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @RoyBanerjee that output is exactly what it should be. Be aware that `cond` is set to `val > 0.33`, I believe you expect `val < 0.33`

Comment: @RoyBanerjee aha ... there was a typo that made the case `< 0.33` fail

Comment: @RoyBanerjee You are welcome. `awk` is an actual programming language and is a very useful tool. If you master it, you can do things very easily. I would recommend to look at this code, try to understand it and to play around with it. The code presented here already contains a lot of awk-tricks. Also if this answer satisfies you, don't forget to accept it. And as always, it was a pleasure helping somebody out.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
c=.33 m=2 perl -lane '
if ($F[1] > $ENV{c}) { push @r, $F[1] }
else {
    if (@r >= $ENV{m}) { print for @r }
    @r = ();
}
END { if (@r >= $ENV{m}) { print for @r } }' -- file
```

It stores the consecutive values into an array @r, if the current value is under threshold, it prints the array if it's long enough.

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` autosplits each line into the @F array
- array used in numeric context retunrs its size
- the %ENV hash contains the environmental variables

If the sequences tend to be very long, you can only store the first `m` elements in the array to save some memory.

```
if ($F[1] > $ENV{c}) {
    push @r, $F[1];
    print shift @r if @r > $ENV{m};
} else {
    if (@r >= $ENV{m}) { print for @r }
    @r = ();
}
END { if (@r >= $ENV{m}) { print for @r } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this awk script:

```
awk -v cutoff="0.33" '
  $2>cutoff{
    if(prev) 
      {print prev ORS $2 } 
    else 
      {prev=$2;next}
  }
  {prev=""}' file
```

It stores the value if above the cutoff in the `prev` variable and resets it at the next number.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use a Bash parameter in awk is like so:

```
$ c=2.3
$ awk -v c="$c" 'BEGIN{print c}'
2.3
```

You can then use that to write you script like so:

```
c=0.33
m=2
awk -v c="$c" -v m="$m" '($2+0!=$2) {next}
                   $2+0<c {cnt=0; split("",lst); next}
                   $2+0>=c && cnt<m {lst[++cnt]=$2}
                   $2+0>=c && cnt==m {for (i=1; i<=m; i++) print lst[i]
                                    cnt=0; split("",lst)}' file
```

That will not print overlapping ranges such as:

```
1 0.34
2 0.3432     # prints 0.34\n0.3432\n here
3 0.35       # unclear if it should print 0.3432\n0.34\n  here....
```

---

Given the update, this will print contiguous runs of lines.

Given:

```
$ cat file
x y
1 0.34
2 0.3432
2a 0.35
3 0.32
4 0.35
5 0.323
6 0.3623
7 0.345
```

You can do:

```
c=0.33
m=2
awk -v c="$c" -v m="$m" '($2+0!=$2) {next}
             $2+0>=c {lst[++cnt]=$2; next}
             $2+0<c { if (cnt>=m) for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++) print lst[i]
                      cnt=0; split("",lst); next}
             END{if (cnt>=m) for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++) print lst[i]}' file
```

Prints:

```
0.34
0.3432
0.35
0.3623
0.345
```

Comment: well it works however the criteria is m='minimum two consecutive values are above c'. That doesn't mean if there is 3 or multiple consecutive values above c it will exclude. m is the minimum requirement. Maybe I was not clear as your script prints out only 2 consecutive values above c. It should minimum 2 consecutive values maximum it can be anything